# jquery return false not Working in Function called from onclientclick button event

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my ASPX page i have declared a jquery function and called it in button's onclientclick function but the return false is not occuring in it

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" Text="Remove" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="submitButton" OnClientClick="CheckConfirm();" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" />

function CheckConfirm() {
            if ($("['txtServerName']").val() != "") {
                var r = confirm("The selected server will be deleted from the Database!!");
                if (r == true) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

I am new To jquery. Please let me know why the return false is not stopping hte event from proceeding.

Comment: You can just `return confirm("...");` in your top level if statement there. And then make sure you return that result in your OnClientClick like Amit shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRemove" Text="Remove" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="submitButton" OnClientClick="return CheckConfirm();" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" />
```

instead of

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" Text="Remove" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="submitButton" OnClientClick="CheckConfirm();" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" />
```

Add `return` in `OnClientClick`